# How to process and insert huge amount of data coming through API in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

In my live website, i need to process and insert very huge amount of data coming through edmunds api. I have 3 tables viz. makes, models, and trims. By connecting with edmunds api, I am getting makes data. Under each makes, I am getting models. And consequently under each model, I will have various trims. I have no problem with makes and models. But trims data is causing a lot of problems. Actually there are more than 2000 rows that need to be inserted in database in one operation.

But I can get all these data for makes and models only when i disable the code for trims. If I enable my code for trims section then makes and models also don't work.

But very surprisingly, all the code for makes, models and trims work on my localhost. I have already used

ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);

in my script to avoid script execution timeout.

So please help me how can I be able to process and insert all the data into my database while working on live site. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Inserting data doesn't take very long for the database. I suspect that the script is dying because of memory limits, not execution time.

Try:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '500M');
```

This allows the script to use up to 500 megabytes of memory so you know it's not a memory issue. If it runs successfully, you can pear it down as you need.

Comment: I also tried it but no success at all. My trims as well as makes and models don't work. How the code is working very fine on my localhost even it did not use memory allocation code?

Comment: Are you on a shared webhost (or any host not in your full control)?

Comment: I think my website is on a shared webhost.

Comment: Then open a ticket with support explaining the problem, maybe link them to this thread. Basically your host could be killing anything that runs for too long or consumes too much memory. When you are on a shared host, you are at their mercy. It's probably something to do with that.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. This is the major drawback of hosting a site built in PHP on a shared hosting environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try use [Mysql transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html). It can help you.